# How to create list of lists, where every first-level list element is assigned the same list

Tags: r, list, loops, recursion, vector

The title sounds very confusing but these are the search terms I was using without luck in finding a solution.

Let's say I have a list. I want to assign another list to every index element of that list. Let's say that list to be assigned is:

```
listChildren <- vector("list", length(childrenNames))
```

The other list, which will be the parent list where it will be assigned to every entry, is:

```
parentList <- vector("list",length(parents))
```

The only way I could figure out how to assign every list element in parentList to listChildren was to loop and assign to every index. That seems very unR-like. So I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it.

```
  i <- 1
  for (name in parentList) {
    # Bad!
    parentList[[i]] <- listChildren
    i <- i + 1
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Tried to make more clear @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Indrajeet has got it @thelatemail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is just:

```
parentList[] <- list(listChildren)
```

Verification (I think?):

```
listChildren <- as.list(1:5)
parentList <- vector("list", 5)

  i <- 1
  for (name in parentList) {
    # Bad!
    parentList[[i]] <- listChildren
    i <- i + 1
  }
pl1 <- parentList

listChildren <- as.list(1:5)
parentList <- vector("list", 5)

parentList[] <- list(listChildren)
pl2 <- parentList

identical(pl1, pl2)
#[1] TRUE
```

This should be about as efficient as it gets from some quick testing on a big set:

```
listChildren <- as.list(1:1000)
parentList <- vector("list", 5e6)

system.time(parentList[] <- list(listChildren))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.03    0.00    0.03 

listChildren <- as.list(1:1000)
parentList <- vector("list", 5e6)

system.time(purrr::map(.x = parentList, .f = function(x) {x <- listChildren}))
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.65    0.00    3.65
```

Comment: Much better than the purr map function (so slow). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
purrr::map(.x = parentList, .f = function(x) {x <- listNames})
```

Comment: Is it vector efficient?

Comment: @incodeveritas Sorry, not sure about efficiency. Maybe other people can comment on that aspect.